# How to connect 3 monitors to a motherboard having only two graphics outputs?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, motherboard, hdmi, integrated-graphics

I have a `i5 10400` PC with `MSI H410M-A Pro` motherboard. Motherboard only has 2 graphics outs - an `HDMI` and a `DVI-D`. I am doing mobile and web development on my PC. I want to connect 3 monitors (2x1080p and 1x720p). I don't want to buy a graphics card just to have 3 graphics outs. Intel has mentioned that i5 10400 Integrated graphics can handle 3 monitors.

<s>Is possible to split `HDMI` or `DVI-D` into two outs so that I can connect 3 monitors to the PC? I checked for splitters but had no luck. Any suggestion will be appreciated.</s>

I don't want a splitter 'cos a splitter would produce the same thing on each screen. I want to have different things on each screen.

[image: MSI specification of graphics outs]

Comment: Back in the days of VGA I once used a VGA splitter.   And if you google HDMI splitter you see loads and loads on google images. So how on earth have you had no luck looking up HDMI splitter Obviously don't just look up "spiltter"!!! To split is to cut something in two. It's not a computer term!!!! You should look up "HDMI Splitter" rather than "splitter"!!

Comment: I am sorry I mostly searched for DVI-D splitters and Few HDMI Splitters. But almost all of them were not possible to connect two monitors to work independently. They just split one video out to two, both monitors will have the identical image (Duplicate/Mirror).

Comment: By "work independently" you mean show different things on the screen.  And regarding the splitters showing the same thing on each screen. Well that's what a splitter does!!!! IT splits the video signal. So of course it won't let two show different things on each screen!!!!!  If it did then it wouldn't be a splitter!!!!!

Comment: Think about it. A splitter splits in two. Like if you have a bottle of lemonade and you have a straw in there, and you split the end of the straw into two to make two streams. You won't get Coca cola out of it.  What is coming out of a display port is already either coca cola or lemonade. Not both!! You would need circuitry long before it reaches the port, to make for two displays showing different things.. Sticking somethin gin the port won't do what you want.

Comment: Yes I understand. Thank you. Found a converter - USB 3.0 to HDMI. Not sure if it works as intended. But looks promising. I will give it try. Anyway thanks for your input.

Comment: well, if it does then post an answer that it does.  And if it doesn't, then add to your question that you tried that, and it doesn't

Comment: I have corrected your question

Comment: Sure. Once I received the converter I will post an update. Thank you!

Comment: I had a Matrox DualHead2Go that was doing what you want, but it had 1 DP input to 2 DVI-D as outputs. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have two outputs which are designed to put out a single image. That means there is no easy way to get 3 independend images.

Your options are:

1. Add a graphics card for more outputs (Regular PCI-e based)
   A cheap one like an AMD 6400 will do.
2. Add a graphics card (USB based). SLOW, but if you just display help files or similar then it will likely suffice.
3. Upgrade your motherboard to one with 3 or more outputs.
4. Use something old an exotic like a fake monitor with high resolution, which outputs to multiple real monitors (e.g. a https://www.matrox.com/en/video/products/gxm/triplehead2go-series/digital-edition)

Of those four adding a extra graphic card probably is the best working one. Not sure why you stated that that is not the route your want to go. Could you add your logic to that to the original post?

Comment: I did not want to buy a graphic card because there is no new graphics card that I can buy within my budget and I afraid of buying used ones. The last time I bought an used one, did not last at least 7 months. I found one of these USB 3.0 to HDMI converters (https://www.amazon.com/USB-Dual-HDMI-Adapter-External/dp/B0725K1MHH/ref=sr_1_4?crid=1KS1Y91VKSHAE&keywords=hdmi%2Bsplitter%2Bfor%2Bdual%2Bmonitors%2Bextended%2Bdisplay&qid=1657872179&sprefix=hdmi%2Bsplitter%2Caps%2C392&sr=8-4&th=1). I think it will work fine in my case.

Comment: I have used similar USB devices int he past. They work, but were noticably slower than a real graphics card. Might be finee to display email, help pages, stack overflow questions etc while coding etc, which seems what you are after. Feels as if you a buying a graphics card but in USB form though.

Comment: @NilupulSandeepa That USB to HDMI converter is actually an additional graphics card that connects to the PC using USB in stead of PCIe. It will work fine, but will be slower than an internal graphics card. Fine for desktop/office work. Not suited for gaming or gfx intensive work like video-editting.

Comment: Yes. I am going to use that monitor connected to USB convert just to view some debug logs while I am developing. So I think it suite me best. Thank you all for your information and help.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot generate more displays than you have sockets.
A splitter will just send the same image to two screens.

If you want three distinct displays you will need a graphics card with at least three outputs [check before buying that it can use all three at once… not all can]